# ios (storyboard) - dismissing sourceViewController after destinationViewController is presented in UIStoryboardSegue

Tags: storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I would like to dismiss sourceViewController(VC2) after destinationViewController(VC3) is presented

[image]

If I use this code, the **destinationViewController(VC3) is not presented at all**:

```
- (void)perform
{
    COSignLogInViewController* sourceViewController = [self sourceViewController];
    COSignLogInViewController* destinationViewController = [self destinationViewController] ;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         my animation
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [sourceViewController presentModalViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO];
                         [sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

                     }];


}
```

If I use this code, the destinationViewController(VC3) is presented, but **immediately dismissed**, and initial VC (VC1) is shown:

```
- (void)perform
{
    COSignLogInViewController* sourceViewController = [self sourceViewController];
    COSignLogInViewController* destinationViewController = [self destinationViewController] ;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         my animation
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [sourceViewController presentModalViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO];
                         [sourceViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

                     }];


}
```

Comment: Is VC2 a Navigation Controller?

Comment: @mxb, VC1 is pushed by Navigation Controller. VC1,  VC2, VC3 are View Controllers

Comment: have you tried to presentModalViewController from VC1?

Comment: @mxb Can I access it in segue between VC2 and VC3?

Comment: not through the Storyboard API, you'll have to pass a reference of VC1 to VC2 before showing VC2

Comment: @mxb Your lead with the navigationController worked. 
I have dismissed sourceViewController and added destinationViewController to navigationController. And it worked. I wrote that as an answer. But if you'll write it by yourself, I'll aprove yours as the correct one.

Comment: thanks for that, I'm posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dismissed sourceViewController and added destinationViewController to navigationController

```
- (void)perform
{
    COSignLogInViewController* sourceViewController = [self sourceViewController];
    COSignLogInViewController* destinationViewController = [self destinationViewController] ;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         my animation
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                         COAppDelegate *del = (COAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                         [del.navigationController presentModalViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO];

                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because VC2 is super class for VC3 if you dismiss super class and presented subclass is not passible.

so you have to use

```
VC1 ->(use push view controller) -> VC2 -> (use present view controller) -> VC3
```

Comment: Maybe in the segue, I can connect V1 to V3 and then dismiss V2?

Comment: you have do not immediately dismissed [sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; But used on custom back button. now then your code worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue calling `presentModalViewController` on the first `ViewController`. If the second view controller does not have a reference to the first view controller you could add a property to be assigned before showing the second view controller or accessing the main view controller from the app delegate if this controller is the first in the application.